# Instantiate a record in Clojurescript from a parameterized record type?

Tags: clojurescript

Is it possible to do the equivalent of the following in Clojurescript?

```
(defn new-record [Type] (Type.))
```

I've tried syntax-quoting, which doesn't seem to work outside of the REPL. Is it possible to instantiate a record without knowing the record type ahead of time?

Answer (score 0):

The following works, with some caveats:

```
(defrecord Foo [])
(defn new-x [x] (new x))
(new-x Foo)
```

The first argument to `new` must be a symbol, not an expression. The following will throw an error:

```
(def x {:foo Foo})
(new-x (:foo x))
```

This is a known issue.